# How can I load a php webpage and send that php webpage a POST without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <ul id = "nav">
        <textarea rows="0" cols="0" name="textBoxStuff" maxlength="0" value="">10</textarea>
        <li><a href="test2">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="test3">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="test4">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="general.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click on any of the links it will load general.js which has the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('content/test1.php');
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function (){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(page + '.php');
        return false;
});
});
```

This will then load the content from test2.php, or test3.php, or test4.php. It depends on which link I press. It will load the content without refreshing the webpage which is what I want. However, in my test2.php file, I want it to output what was written in the textbox on the main page.

This is the code in test2.php:

```
<?php
    $textBoxStuff = $_POST['textBoxStuff'];
    echo $testBoxStuff;
    echo '<h1>Home</h1>';
?>
```

So the word "Home" is properly showing up when I click Home on the main page, but I don't know how to send the $_POST['textBoxStuff']; to the test2.php file. The $_POST['textBoxStuff'] should be equal to whatever was inside the textarea on the main webpage. So my question is if anyone knows how to send the data from the textbox from the mainpage to my test2.php file without refreshing the webpage, so using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a second parameter to the `.load()` method to tell jQuery what to send to the server.
eg:

```
$('#content').load(page + '.php', {
       textBoxStuff: document.getElementsByName("textBoxStuff")[0].value
});
```

Comment: The textBoxStuff: document.getElementsByName("textBoxStuff")[0].value wasn't working for me, but I added an id on the textbox, and used textBoxStuff: document.getElementById("invisTest").value, and now it works. You helped a lot man. I was actually trying to figure this out myself for 8 hours until I finally gave in to stack overflow.